# Do sub-directories inherit properties such as add_definitions, include_directories and variables set in parent Cmakelist.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project. In one of my directories, I have multiple directories. The Cmakelist.txt of the parent directory looks as below. (It is not complete yet !! No executable added.)

```css
add_definitions(
-DMODEL=demo -DSTACK_SIZE=64 )


include_directories(
"D:/Project/newCmakeTest"
"D:/Project/newCmakeTest/src"
)

add_subdirectory(common)
add_subdirectory(subfolder1)
add_subdirectory(subfolder2)

string (REPLACE "-Werror" "" CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
string (REPLACE "-Werror" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fpermissive -Wno-narrowing")
```

I am wondering whether the properties such as add_definitions and include_directories will be inherited by corresponding in subfolder1, subfolder2 and common

Answer (score 1):

Effects of **almost every action** in `CMakeLists.txt` are **propagated to the subdirectories** (assuming `add_subdirectory` is called *after* the action).

`add_definitions` and `include_directories` follows that propagation strategy.